# C++ Eigen inverse matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, inverse

I am trying to calculate the inverse of a matrix in c++ using Eigen.
The inverse calculated is wrong, as I tried multiplying the original matrix with its inverse and I did not get the Identity matrix.
I also checked if the matrix is singular by calculating its determinant, but that was not 0.
The matrix is a dynamic-size matrix of doubles, which gets filled with values inside a function.
In the code it looks like this:
`Eigen::MatrixXd inverse_ee = knotenadmittanzmatrix_ee.inverse();`

I added pictures of the matrix "knotenadmittanzmatrix_ee" (Knotenadmittanz Extern-Extern), and the inverse I get (Knotenadmittanz Extern-Extern invertiert).
[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: It looks like the determinant of your matrix is 0, indeed. Isn't it strange that the full matrix is filled with the same value? That might be the origin of your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *not the identity matrix* ? How much does it differ from it?

Comment: No, the matrix with alle the same value is the "inverted" one.

Comment: When I multiply the matrix with its "inverse", the outcome has a row with numbers around -20. That is what I meant with not the identity matrix.

Comment: Can you print the determinant of the original matrix?

Comment: Determinant is 7.2e-08

Comment: `7.2e-8` is essentially zero compared to the scale of your matrix. You can try to compute a pseudo inverse, if that helps. (N.B.: Please post your matrix as text not as an image, in case somebody wants to try this locally).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigen is Failing to Give Correct Matrix Inverse (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059268/eigen-is-failing-to-give-correct-matrix-inverse-c)